# How to include files from an amended commit in a listing of changed files during a git hook

Tags: git

I'm trying to write a git pre-commit hook, and I want to run some linter against all the files that belong to the commit. Some quick searching on Google/on StackOverflow suggests that the solution is `git diff --cached --name-only` or `git status --porcelain`. But neither of these will include files that belong to a commit that is being amended, but weren't changed *this time*. As an example, here's a `git log --name-only` in my current repo. I've left out the commit info because it's irrelevant; but the file list produced is as follows:

```
.husky/pre-commit
src/controllers/v2/api/comic/add_item.rs
src/controllers/v2/api/comic/patch_comic.rs
src/controllers/v2/api/comic/remove_item.rs
src/controllers/v2/api/item/image.rs
src/controllers/v2/api/item/patch_item.rs
src/util.rs
```

now I've made some changes and `git status` says

```
Changes to be committed:
  (use "git reset HEAD <file>..." to unstage)

        modified:   .husky/pre-commit
```

In my `pre-commit` script, I have the following lines:

```bash
git diff --cached --name-only --diff-filter=ACMRT
git status --porcelain
```

Running `git commit --amend` causes the `pre-commit` hook to output:

```
# this is the diff output:
.husky/pre-commit
# this is the status output:
 M .husky/clippy-dirty
MM .husky/pre-commit
```

As you can see, the `diff` is only showing files I've modified *since* the initial commit, and the `status` is showing the same *and* other unstaged changes. But what I want is *what is being committed right now*, whether those changes happened previously (i.e. the first time the commit happened) or currently (i.e. the new changes being amended).

In a more general sense, it'd be nice if I could get a list of files that is correct no matter the circumstance, even during rebasing and such. Since I can't even get a simple `commit --amend` to work right, I haven't tested this on rebases yet.